# Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies? That's illegal

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am trying to create UIButtons programmatically with constraints. it should create buttons on basis of items in array.

I have taken UIView outlets as a viewSingle and given leading, bottom ,trailing and height constraints in storyboard.  Now, when I am trying to constraint the UIButton programmatically it gives below mentioned error.

```
for (index,item) in (self.planModel.plan_settings?.sticky_buttons?.enumerated())!{

        var btnOne = UIButton()
        var btnSecond = UIButton()
        var btnThird = UIButton()

        let totalItems = self.planModel.plan_settings?.sticky_buttons?.count ?? 1

        let multiplier = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(totalItems)) / UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        switch index {
        case 0:
            btnOne = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
            btnOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            viewSingle.addSubview(btnOne)

            btnOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                btnOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
                btnOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle.topAnchor, constant: 0),
                // button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle!.widthAnchor, constant: 0),
                btnOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle!.heightAnchor, constant: 0),
                btnOne.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle.widthAnchor, multiplier: multiplier, constant: 0)
                ])
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        case 1:
            btnSecond = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
            btnSecond.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            viewSingle.addSubview(btnSecond)

            btnSecond.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                btnSecond.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnOne.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
                btnSecond.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle.topAnchor, constant: 0),
                // button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle!.widthAnchor, constant: 0),
                btnSecond.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle!.heightAnchor, constant: 0),
                btnSecond.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle.widthAnchor, multiplier: multiplier, constant: 0)
                ])
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        case 2:
            btnThird = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
            btnThird.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            viewSingle.addSubview(btnThird)

            btnThird.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                btnThird.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
                btnThird.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle.topAnchor, constant: 0),
                // button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle!.widthAnchor, constant: 0),
                btnThird.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle!.heightAnchor, constant: 0),
                btnThird.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSingle.widthAnchor, multiplier: multiplier, constant: 0)
                ])
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        default:
            break
        }


    }
```

Error:-

> 2017-12-06 19:16:03.601661+0530 WayOL[8637:3028327] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your code, and you may not have shown it, but I'm not seeing where you are adding any subviews.

Comment: Tough to figure out what you are trying to do... Is your goal to add 1, 2 or 3 buttons to `viewSingle`, with equal widths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are creating ***NEW*** buttons each time through the loop:

```
for (index,item) in (self.planModel.plan_settings?.sticky_buttons?.enumerated())!{

        var btnOne = UIButton()
        var btnSecond = UIButton()
        var btnThird = UIButton()

        // rest of code inside loop
}
```

So, the first time through the loop, `index` equals 0, and you add `btnOne` as a subview of `viewSingle`.

The *next* time through the loop, you create a ***new*** `btnOne` -- then you add `btnSecond` to `viewSingle` and try to constrain it to the ***new*** `btnOne`, which hasn't been added to `viewSingle`.

If you create your 3 button vars *outside* the loop - such as the same level where you create `viewSingle`, then remove any `= UIButton(...)` statements from inside the loop, you won't get that error.

Not sure if your overall `totalItems` and `multiplier` calculations and the rest of your constraints will actually do what you want though. You may need to re-think your approach (you haven't shown / explained what you're going for, so tough to say).